# Data Table merge

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to handle Concurrency exceptions and am experiencing unexpected behavior when merging two datatables. The first datatable is "Tbl" and holds data from the Employees table when the form was originally opened. After changing the FirstName of an employee on the form and changing the FirstName of that same employee to something else in the underlying database, closing the form attempts to update Tbl and the concurrency exception is triggered.

I then retrieve the current values for that same employee from the database and add that data to "TmpTbl". Both Tbl and TmpTbl contains the primary key. Then I try to merge the two datatables expecting values in Tbl to be updated from the values in TmpTbl. Instead, I end up with two rows with the same primary key in Tbl. The pertinent code follows:

```
'Populate the data displayed on the form.
CN.ConnectionString = ConnStr()
DA.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("Select ID, LastName, FirstName, MidInit From Employees Where Deleted Is Null And TermDate Is Null Order By " &
                                          "LastName, FirstName, MidInit", CN)
DA.Fill(Tbl)
'Get values currently in the underlying database.
Dim TmpTbl As New DataTable
Dim DAA As New SqlDataAdapter
DAA.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("Select ID, LastName, FirstName, MidInit From Employees Where ID = " & DBCX.Row.Item("ID"), CN)
DAA.Fill(TmpTbl)
'Merge the two tables.
Tbl.Merge(TmpTbl, True)
```

After the merge, I have two of the same rows in Tbl when as I understand it, there should be only one with the values updated from TmpTbl.
Any help would be greatly appreciated since my app for the client is used in a multi-user environment.

Larry

Comment: Note: use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: You could save a lot of trouble by updating `Tbl` directly at the same time you save changes to the database. Have `Try` block that saves the data first, and updates `Tbl` second, so the Tbl change only happens if the database write succeeds. This will perform FAR better, and save you a lot of this effort.

Comment: What do you see if you check `Tbl.PrimaryKey` in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should do is not try to re-use the same connection object (`CN`). Thanks to ADO.Net connection pooling, you really are better off creating a brand new connection for most queries, rather than trying to re-use the same one throughout your app. This is one potential source of concurrency problems.

Another thing you should do is **use parameterized queries**, instead of string concatenation, to put data like ID values into your SQL commands. ***I can't over-state how important this is!***

Finally, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-7.0#system-data-datatable-merge(system-data-datatable-system-boolean)) says this about the `preserveChanges` argument:

> If the `preserveChanges` parameter is set to `true`, incoming values do not overwrite existing values in the Current row version of the existing row.

Seems like you want that to be `False`

Put it all together like this:

```vb
Dim SQL As String = "
SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName, MidInit
FROM Employees 
WHERE ID = @ID
"

Dim result As New DataTable
Using Cn  As New SqlConnection(ConnStr), _
      Cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Cn), _
      Da  As New SqlDataAdapter(Cmd)

    Cmd.Paramaters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBCX.Row.Item("ID")
    Da.Fill(result)
End Using
Tbl.Merge(result, False)
```

Comment: Joel, I tried Tbl.Merge with the Preserve Changes parameter set  to True and again with it set to False. In both cases, it simply added the one row from TmpTbl (your "result") to Tbl causing Tbl to have two rows with the same ID (primary key)and did not change any values in the matching row in Tbl.

I've always used concatenation in my queries and never experienced any problems. What issues are you aware of?

Comment: @LarryStinson If all you do is concatenation, it's trivial to put `';` at the beginning of any text input followed by whatever arbitrary SQL I want to run. This can include things like dropping tables or inserting known hash values over top of password fields to gain full system access. Sometimes devs will try to get around this by "sanitizing" these characters (`myinputstring.Replace("'", "''")`, but this is only a half measure. There are tricks we can use to break out of this, including certain unicode characters or less-known string features in SQL. Query parameters are the way to go

Comment: @LarryStinson As a bonus, parameterized queries also improve performance by allowing the database to cache query execution plans. Using them saves most of the compilation step for nearly every impacted query, and that can add up.

Comment: As for the specific issue, if `False` does not work, then I'd expect one datatable or the other does not have the proper primary key definition. You can use the debugger to check for this.

Comment: You were correct. despite including the primary key column of the table in my Select statement, there was no primary key value in the two tables. FYI After I added the primary key to the tables, the Tbl.Merge(TmpTbl, True) changed the columns in Tbl to the values in the database AND preserved the changes I had already made to Tbl, thereby eliminating the DBConcurrencyException from the DA.Update(Tbl). Thank you!